# Outlook add-in with React not visible for shared mail box

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have created an `Outlook add-in` to move emails/attachments to **SharePoint** which works fine for user mailbox but when I move to the shared mailbox the add-in is `not visible`

> Inside get add-ins to tab the add-in is visible but not visible on the ribbon.

We have configured shared mailbox in **Exchange** and is auto mapped to outlook. The `SupportsSharedFolders` is set to `true` and there are no issues while installing the manifest.

Did I miss any step in configuration?

Please help to get the add-in started for the shared mailbox.

EDIT: Im including the manifest file below. Just found that the desktop client is using version override 1.0 and Web and mobile are using version override 1.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>1111111111111</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.4</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso E-mail"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Contoso E-mail"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.Contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.windows.net</AppDomain>

  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html">
         <Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="https://localhost:3000/taskpane_nl.html" />
        </SourceLocation>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon16.png">
          <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon16.png" />
          </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon32.png">
           <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon32.png" />
           </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon80.png">
           <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon80.png" />
           </bt:Image>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso E-mail"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Contoso E-mail"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
  <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <MobileFormFactor>
    <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
      <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
        <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
        <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="TaskPaneBtn">
          <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
          <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
            <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="Icon.25x25" />
            <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="Icon.25x25" />
            <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="Icon.25x25" />

            <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="Icon.32x32" />
            <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="Icon.32x32" />
            <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="Icon.32x32" />

            <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="Icon.48x48" />
            <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="Icon.48x48" />
            <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="Icon.48x48" />
          </Icon>
          <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
            <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
          </Action>
        </Control>
      </Group>
    </ExtensionPoint>
  </MobileFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon16.png">
          <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon16.png" />
          </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon32.png">
          <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon32.png" />
          </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon80.png">
           <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="https://localhost:3000/assets/Icon80.png" />
           </bt:Image>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso E-mail"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Contoso E-mail"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    
  </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Namrata Sah. Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so SO users can help you with a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that "SupportsSharedFolders" is set true but the manifest you shared does not have "SupportsSharedFolders". Please add "SupportsSharedFolders" as mentioned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/supportssharedfolders) and check.

Comment: Now that I have added "SupportsSharedFolders", the addin is not appearing in mobile.